# Icon navigation menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, icons

I'm trying to add an area to my navigation on the right hand side, I only want it to contain the three icons which are basket, search and the wish list.

Does anyone know what the best way would be to achieve this? I'm currently using the Divi theme on this site.

Also, I'm trying to use an icon instead of text as a link for the wish list but it didn't seem to work. I have the font awesome plug-in downloaded and used the following code in the custom menu label.

( [website referred to above link](http://florest.uk.w3pcloud.com)  )

```html
<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
```

Thanks.

Comment: fas/far works for the latest font-awesome 5 icons... https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this I Tag

```
<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can create a widget and define widget on right side of menu.
create dynamic sidebar in **function.php**.

add dynamic sidebar as widget in **appearence --> widget**.
add dynamic sidebar in page as

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar name' ); ?>.
```

```css
ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0
}
ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
ul li a{
 color:#000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>  
  <li>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Would the functionality of the search still work for this? Also how would i make the widget display to the left of the navigation if i did this.

Comment: you can put id of search div 'et_top_search' to search icon and may be it works.you have to put the sidebar name with php code as show in post.just put it after menu code with sidebar name you used.

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling a little with the php side, should i be put the top bit of php code in the function.php file?

Comment: Please could you post the instruction a little more clearly for me? I'm not the best coder, It'd be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you can check it from this link
https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/add-widget-areas-to-wordpress-guide/